# Name of a particular category

Tags: reference-request, category-theory, terminology

I'd like to work with a certain category which seems classic to me, but I don't know its usual name.

Let's define $$Ob(\mathcal{C}) = \{(Y,Y_1,Y_2,f) : Y = Y_1 \cup Y_2, f : Y_1 \to Y_2\},$$ where $Y,Y_1,Y_2$ are sets and $f$ a function. And
$$Hom((Y,Y_1,Y_2,f),(Z,Z_1,Z_2,g)) = \{h : Y \to Z : h(Y_1)\subset Z_1, h(Y_2)\subset Z_2, h\circ f = g\circ h\}.$$ Thank you for any answer or reference.

Comment: Are you using $\sqcup$ for union or disjoint union? (or something else?)

Comment: Sorry this is a union.

Answer (score 1):

**Edit.** After the OP's edit of the question, it doesn't answer on it. Just an observation: the category you are describing is a wide subcategory of $\mathbf{Set}^{\rightarrow}$.

This category (with $\sqcup$ instead of $\cup$) is isomorphic to the category of arrows of $\mathbf{Set}$. Indeed, a quadruple $(Y,Y_1,Y_2,f)$ is simply a function between sets and a function $h\colon Y_1\sqcup Y_2\to Z_1\sqcup Z_2$, such that $h(Y_1)\subset Z_1$ and $h(Y_2)\subset Z_2$, is simply a pair of functions $(h_1\colon Y_1\to Z_1,h_2\colon Y_2\to Z_2)$.

Comment: I am sorry, I made a mistake, this is the normal union.